# Excel VBA give numbers to specified cells, avoid Select

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I have following VBA code in Excel. It is a part of very long VBA responsible for a lot of processes. How I can get rid of Select command? I have tried several things with no success.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Installation").Select
    For Each Cl14 In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Installation").Range("G2", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      Select Case LCase(Cl14.Value)
         Case "main"
            m14 = m14 + 1: s14 = 0: ss14 = 0
            Cl14.Offset(, -6).Value = m14
         Case "sub"
            s14 = s14 + 1: ss14 = 0
            Cl14.Offset(, -6) = m14 & "." & s14
         Case "sub-sub"
            ss14 = ss14 + 1
            Cl14.Offset(, -6) = m14 & "." & s14 & "." & ss14
      End Select
   Next Cl14
```

Comment: Are you saying that, if you replace `ThisWorkbook` by `ActiveWorkbook` and you delete the line with `Select`, that is doesn't work?

Comment: Oh, I just see a `Rows.count` in your `For Each` loop. What does this `Rows` refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the Range objects using a `With` statement. Consider replacing your variable names with something more meaningful. I have only changed one. Also, use `Option Explici`t at the top of your code and declare all your variables with type.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, iCell As Range, m14 As Long, s14 As Long, ss14 As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Installation")

    With ws
        For Each iCell In .Range("G2", .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            Select Case LCase(iCell.Value)
            Case "main"
                m14 = m14 + 1: s14 = 0: ss14 = 0
                iCell.Offset(, -6).Value = m14
            Case "sub"
                s14 = s14 + 1: ss14 = 0
                iCell.Offset(, -6) = m14 & "." & s14
            Case "sub-sub"
                ss14 = ss14 + 1
                iCell.Offset(, -6) = m14 & "." & s14 & "." & ss14
            End Select
        Next iCell
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

can do a force loop to prevent the select case. But personally i like to use select case more.

```
For i = 2 To .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If .Range("G" & i).Value = "main" Then
'code here
ElseIf .Range("G" & i).Value = "sub" Then
'code here
ElseIf .Range("G" & i).Value = "sub-sub" Then
'code here
End If
Next i
```